# Triggering FireWatir actions from different ruby scripts on the same browser window

Tags: ruby-on-rails, watir, firewatir

I am writing an application that uses FireWatir to do a bunch of different actions.  The problem is that I want to trigger these actions from many separate ruby files.

So for example, one ruby script will launch a new FireFox browser instance, than a totally different script will have that instance goto a specific website, and another will log into gmail.

I want all of these scripts to affect the same browser window.  That way I can have one script take me to a specific website, and wait for another script to be triggered to do something else.

Please tell me that this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Chad,

I think that is possible. I am not sure that it's necessary or efficient, but I know that it's possible. The key is to make sure that you attach to the right browser instance. If you will only have one, that could be much simpler.

If you identify the problem that you are trying to solve with these *multiple scripts* then maybe one or more of the experienced framework designers can point you to existing solutions to the problem. There are some pretty awesome solutions that exist already. At the end of the day, we face the same issues.

Good luck,

Dave

Answer (score 1):

I ended up getting around this issue by using socketing.  Had a ruby script acting as the server that was waiting for requests from another group of ruby scripts that could be triggered whenever.